# Justice League in Lois and Clark

Tags: dc, superman, justice-league, lois-and-clark

Did any Justice League characters such as Oliver Queen, Aquaman ever appear in the Dean Cain/Teri Hatcher 90's Lois and Clark Adventures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to both the [IMDB full cast page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106057/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) and the [Wikia fan site](http://lois-and-clark-the-new-adventures-of-superman.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Heroes), the answer is **no**.

Comment: Ok thx, just tidying up my questions.